# Laravel Cartalyst Sentinel - Adding a username column to users table (What is the right way)

Tags: php, laravel, acl, cartalyst-sentinel

I've pulled in cartalyst/sentinel and i've run the migrations required to generate the tables

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentinel
```

I notice that these are the columns available in the users table

1. id
2. email
3. password
4. permissions
5. last_login
6. first_name
7. last_name
8. created_at
9. updated_at

I'd like to add username after the email. So i created a migration file that does that.

```
//add a column username after email in the users table
$table->string('username')->after('email')->unique();
```

Now when i use Sentinel::register

```
$credentials = Input::all();
$user = Sentinel::register($credentials);
```

The username doesn't get saved in the table. So i've managed to get it fillable by editing **vendor/cartalyst/sentinel/src/Users/EloquentUser.php**

```
protected $fillable = [
    'email',
    'username', /* i added this */
    'password',
    'last_name',
    'first_name',
    'permissions',
];
```

Now this works, the username gets stored in the table. But im **wondering if what i'm doing is right?** Should we not touch the files in the packages folder. How do we solve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Almost. You have to create your own User clas, extending `vendor/cartalyst/sentinel/src/Users/EloquentUser.php`:

```
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser as CartalystUser;

class User extends CartalystUser {

    protected $fillable = [
        'email',
        'username', /* i added this */
        'password',
        'last_name',
        'first_name',
        'permissions',
    ];

}
```

Publish Sentinel's config:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentinel
```

And in the config file, set the user model to your own:

```
'users' => [

    'model' => 'Your\Namespace\User',

],
```

Comment: Does authentifiation work with Sentinel::authenticate(['username'=>'user','password'=>'password']) ? I know it requires an array with 'email' and 'password' by default.