# Cartalyst Sentinel user registration with custom fields (solved)

Tags: laravel-7, cartalyst-sentinel

Good evening.
I added a boolean field "privacy_ok" to my user model and migration.

**migration file**

```
 Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('last_name',100)->nullable();
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('privacy_ok')->default(0);
        $table->text('permissions')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_login')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->unique('email');
    });
```

**App\User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

protected $fillable = [
    'first_name','last_name','email', 'password', 'privacy_ok'
];

....
```

When I try to register my user, the new field is skipped.

```
$user = Sentinel::register($request->all());
```

I noticed that, if I cause an error (a duplicate email address... for example), the INSERT query does show the "privacy_ok" field.

Is there a way to solve that?

Do I have to user User::create and than "convert" it into a Cartalyst Sentinel object to go on with all the other operations (such as activation, for example) ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I found some info here
[Laravel Cartalyst Sentinel - Adding a username column to users table (What is the right way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133447/laravel-cartalyst-sentinel-adding-a-username-column-to-users-table-what-is-th)

Now I have a new file App\Models\Cartalyst\User.php, but when I add it to the cartalyst config file  ( **config/cartalyst.sentinel.php** ), I receive an error.

```
'users' => [
    // 'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser',
    'model' => 'App\Models\Cartalyst\User',
],
```

***Cannot declare class User, because the name is already in use***

Of course the user is there even if I change User to Lorem. It's not a naming issue.

**SOLVED**
I forgot to declare the namespace in the header of the new class! :(

Comment: Try by regenerate classes `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks. I found the issue... 
I modify my post to let everybody knows